# Regarding the scope of functions(parameters) in a loop in C

Tags: c, function, parameters, while-loop, scope

I have a question regarding the scope of parameters in C. I'm new to C and I have been working on a problem, and one of the TA's gave me a function getline() after I struggled

```
int main(void) {

  printf("Type a string, then hit enter\n");
  printf("You may type strings after an enter, but you must hit enter again to     record the new string\n");
  fflush( stdout );
  int len;
  char line[Limit];


  while((len=getline(line,Limit))>0) 
  {
    reverse(line);
    printf("%s",line);
  }
}
```

Which calls function getline() defined as:

```
int getline(char s[], int lim){
  int i,c;
  for(i=0;i<lim-1 &&((c=getchar())!=EOF) && (c !='\n');++i)
    s[i]=c;

  if(c== '\n')//if c is a newline
  {
    s[i]=c; 
    ++i;
  }
  s[i]= '\0';
  return i;
}
```

Since `char line[limit]` gets passed into `getline()` in the while condition. `getline()` does work on `line[]` and changes it's value.

My question is once on iteration of the loop is done, when `getline()` is called again in the while loop, does it still retain it's value from the first iteration or does it get reset?

I know `line[]` is empty after exiting the while loop, but I want to know the nuances of it in the loop itself.

For example if I enter to stdin:

```
"Hello\n
"How are you\n"
```

`line[]="Hello\n\0"` when `getline()` finishes the first iteration of the while loop. When `getline()` get's called again for iteration 2, is `line[]="Hello\n\0"` ? (Pretending reverse doesn't exist) and gets overwritten or is `line[]="\0"`?

If reverse didn't exist (makes it irrelevant whether one string is longer for the print) and I entered

```
"How are you\n
Hello\n"
```

would `line[]="Hello\n\0you\n\0"`? after the second iteration before the while ends?

Comment: What is "it" in "when getline() is called again in the while loop, does it still retain it's value from the first iteration or does it get reset?"

Comment: There's no reason for the array contents to get "reset" while it's still in scope, unless something explicitly modifies them.  So yes, it retains whatever was placed in it last time.  Also after exiting the loop `line` isn't emptied, it just has a null character at the start because `getline()` put one there the last time the loop condition was evaluated... that corresponds to a zero character string, but the rest of the array still has the remnants of whatever was read before.

Comment: "it' is the value of the char array line

Comment: Okay I think I understand what @Dmitri is saying after looking over it. Since getline() gets executed regardless if it's >0 or not, line[]'s value is getting changed. So the third time the return value of i=0 but s[i] would still get set to '\0'. So if I didn't manually put a manual null terminating string if i was=0 then line[] would have the value of the second iteration

Comment: Alright, so line isn't really empty after second iteration of the while(in your example), but when you try to printf("%s", line), since the leading element is '\0', the print is empty so it appeared empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Since char line[limit] gets passed into getline() in the while condition. getline() does work on line[] and changes it's value. My question is once on iteration of the loop is done, when getline() is called again in the while loop, does it still retain it's value from the first iteration or does it get reset?

Array `line` is declared outside the loop.  Its innermost enclosing block is the one that serves as the whole body of function `main()`; its lifetime is from the declaration to the end of that block.  For the duration of that lifetime, the declared identifier, `line`, always designates the same object, and that object retains its value, except as that value may be modified explicitly by your program.  In particular, if the array were declared with an initializer, that initializer would be applied only once, when the array first came into existence.

Thus, the `line` array does retain its value from one iteration of the loop to the next.  However, the very first thing done in each iteration of the loop is to test the loop condition, which requires calling `getline()`, which modifies some or all of that array's elements.  Thus, the statements in the loop body will see new array contents on every iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in C, arrays are pass-by-reference meaning that instead of passing the entire array into the function, your program is passing a pointer to the memory address that stores the array. This means when you modify it in the function, it also modifies it in the outer code. When you add more characters to s in `getline`, you are also adding characters to `line` in `main()`.

Comment: Detail: When an array is passed as an augment to a function, it is converted to the address of its first element, _before the function is called_.  The function receives a copy of that address.  So some-what like "pass-by-reference", from the array POV, but in detail, still pass by value.  In this case, the pointer was passed, and passed by value.

Comment: Okay, so line[] is getting continually overwritten and it retains it's value even after the while loop is done. Dmitri cleared it up a little why in my code line[] would also = "\0" when the loop ends. If it wasn't set up like that(and I see why it is concerning the problem) then lines[] would contain the most recent string concatenated with the characters of the biggest string passed in that was greater than the char# of the most recent string.